# WebService Restful Jersey

Tags: java, web-service, restful, jersey

Estou iniciando o desenvolvimento de WebService Restful Jersey em Java e não estou conseguindo conectar para realizar um simples Hello World.

Adicionei os jar:

- asm-3.1jar
- jersey-core-1.19jar
- jersey-server-1.19jar
- jersey-servlet-1.19jar
- jrr311-api.1.1.1.jar

Criei a classe Hello:

```
package com.k19.restful.resources; 

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;  

@Path("/helloworld") 
public class Hello {

    @GET @Produces("text/plain") 
    public String showHelloWorld() { 
        return "Olá mundo!"; 
    }

}
```

Configurei o web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app> 
    <display-name>jersey-tutorial</display-name>
    <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name> 
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param> 
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name> 
            <param-value>com.k19.restful.resources</param-value>
        </init-param> 
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Estou utilizando o Tomcat, ele inicializa normalmente... porém quando vou entrar na url:

http://localhost:8080/jersey-tutorial/helloworld

Dá o erro 404. A porta é a 8080...

Existe algum outro procedimento que preciso fazer?

Log gerado na inicialização do TomCat:

```
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
Advertência: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ExemploWS' did not find a matching property.
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.59
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: Server built:          Jan 28 2015 15:51:10 UTC
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: Server number:         7.0.59.0
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: OS Name:               Windows 7
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: OS Version:            6.1
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: Architecture:          amd64
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: JVM Version:           1.7.0_01-b08
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\paula\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\paula\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\paula\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
Informações: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
Informações: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Sony\VAIO Improvement\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;.
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Informações: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Informações: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Informações: Initialization processed in 1340 ms
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Informações: Starting service Catalina
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Informações: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.59
[WARN] Web application uses org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet; please update web.xml to use org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet instead
[INFO] Clustering has been disabled
[INFO] Deploying module: addressing-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/paula/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ExemploWS/WEB-INF/modules/addressing-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: metadataExchange-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/paula/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ExemploWS/WEB-INF/modules/mex-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: mtompolicy-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/paula/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ExemploWS/WEB-INF/modules/mtompolicy-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: ping-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/paula/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ExemploWS/WEB-INF/modules/ping-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: script-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/paula/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ExemploWS/WEB-INF/modules/scripting-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: soapmonitor-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/paula/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ExemploWS/WEB-INF/modules/soapmonitor-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying Web service: UsuarioDAO - file:/C:/Users/paula/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ExemploWS/WEB-INF/services/UsuarioDAO/
[INFO] Deploying Web service: version.aar - file:/C:/Users/paula/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ExemploWS/WEB-INF/services/version.aar
[WARN] No transportReceiver for org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener found. An instance for HTTP will be configured automatically. Please update your axis2.xml file!
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Informações: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Informações: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mai 01, 2015 8:43:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Informações: Server startup in 7000 ms
```

Comment: tente colocar no seu método também por exemplo  @Path("/showHelloWorld") e acessar depois: http://localhost:8080/jersey-tutorial/helloworld/showHelloWorld

Comment: Paula, testei seu exemplo aqui e está OK. Você pode incluir o log de startup do tomcat? Talvez pelo log conseguimos ver o que pode ser. Provavelmente "classes raízes" não foram encontradas, por isto o 404, ou seja, não publicou o recurso.

Comment: Bruno, posso sim! Abri no eclipse um webservice que já tinha feito com SOAP e rodou certinho. Eu acho que está faltando alguma configuração, por exemplo a axis.Vou editar a pergunta e colocar o log

Comment: Paula, obrigado por atualizar. Mas seria necessário o log do tomcat iniciando com o `jersey-tutorial` e não com outro projetos. O problema não é a falta do `axis`, ele é uma implementação SOAP. Tente iniciar o tomcat apenas com o `jersey-tutorial` publicado que pelo log talvez eu consiga lhe ajudar. Também, caso possível, mostre a estrutura de diretórios de `jersey-tutorial`, pode ser que o `web.xml` não esteja sendo publicado.